# ¿Por qué el cursor no me muestra los datos si la consulta si los trae?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure

Estoy haciendo un procedimiento almacenado para ver mejor los datos de la DB, pero soy nuevo en esto y estoy aprendiendo.

Este es mi código:

```
 
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `mostrarEncuesta`(in anio_encuesta int, in preguntas_vigentes int, in con_datos_backend int, in con_datos_frontend int)
BEGIN
        DECLARE done int(1) DEFAULT 0;

        DECLARE ano_consultado int(4); -- Variable para validar el año consultado
    
        # Variables para encabezado de tabla
        DECLARE nombre_seccion varchar(100);
        DECLARE ruta_ids varchar(20);
        DECLARE ruta_valores varchar(100);
        DECLARE pregunta_o_alternativa varchar(300);
        # Fin de variables de encabezado de tabla
        
        DECLARE error varchar(50);
        
        # Cursor que valida el año consultado
        DECLARE cursor_anio_registrado CURSOR FOR 
            SELECT id_ano 
            FROM ano 
            WHERE id_ano = anio_encuesta;

        # Cursor para guardar las secciones de la encuesta
        DECLARE cursorSecciones CURSOR FOR 
            SELECT nombre_seccion
            FROM seccion;
        
        
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done = 1;
    
    
    # Valida que el año buscado exista en la DB
    SET ano_consultado = null;
    OPEN cursor_anio_registrado;
    FETCH cursor_anio_registrado INTO ano_consultado;
    IF NOT done THEN 
    # Fin de validación de año
        
        OPEN cursorSecciones;
            REPEAT
                FETCH cursorSecciones INTO nombre_seccion;


                    SET ruta_ids = "HOLA";
                    SET ruta_valores = "HOLA";
                    SET pregunta_o_alternativa = "HOLA";

                  SELECT nombre_seccion, ruta_ids, ruta_valores, pregunta_o_alternativa;
                 
            
            UNTIL done END REPEAT;
        CLOSE cursorSecciones;
        
    ELSE 
        SET error = "No se encontró el año especificado";
        SELECT error;
    END IF;
    
    CLOSE cursor_anio_registrado; -- Cierra el cursor que valida el año consultado
END
```

Y acá en la imagen, detallo las líneas que me tienen complicado. Primero la consulta carga datos, pero luego el cursor no los muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué podrá ser? Me he estado guiando por el ejemplo completo de esta web, pero lo veo igual: http://tisbddocs.dlsi.ua.es/inicio/sql/practicas-sql-espanol/procedimientos

[ACTUALIZACIÓN]
Bueno, probé pasar el valor del cursor a una consulta y luego mostrar. Y funcionó.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, me gustaría saber por qué era necesario pasar el valor del cursor al where de una consulta y luego encontrar el valor que buscaba. Lo veo como hacer pasos de más.

Comment: Las SP admiten tres tipos de parámetros: `IN` (de entrada), `OUT` (de salida), `INOUT` (de entrada/salida). En tu SP no estás declarando ningún parámetro de salida, por tanto no podrás obtener nada en respuesta desde ella. Revisa [este tutorial](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-parameters.aspx) sobre los parámetros.

Comment: Gracias, @A.Cedano voy a revisar el tutorial que me pasaste. =)